# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when executing macroexpand-1 on this Clojure macro?

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm in the process of learning Clojure macros, and I'm getting a NullPointerException when trying to use macroexpand-1 on this macro:

```
(def config {:ns 'bulbs.neo4jserver.client, 
             :root-uri "http://localhost:7474/db/data/"})
(def data {:name "James"})

(defmacro create
  [config data]
  `(~(ns-resolve (:ns config) 'create-vertex) config data))

(macroexpand-1 '(create config data))
```

Trying to compile this returns:

```
 Unknown location:
   error: java.lang.NullPointerException

 Compilation failed.
```

But evaluating the macro's body...

```
`(~(ns-resolve (:ns config) 'create-vertex) config data)
```

...returns this...

```
(#'bulbs.neo4jserver.client/create-vertex bulbs.vertices/config bulbs.vertices/data)
```

...which is what I think I want.

UPDATE: If I manually replace `(:ns config)` with `'bulbs.neo4jserver.client` then the error goes away -- how do you make `(:ns config)` play nice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to mix macroexpand-time and runtime information. The local "config" does not contain the contents of the #'config var, but instead is the symbol 'config.

If you look at the full stack trace, not just the error message, you'll see that ns-resolve is being passed a nil:

```
user=> (pst)
NullPointerException 
        java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get (ConcurrentHashMap.java:796)
        clojure.lang.Namespace.find (Namespace.java:188)
        clojure.core/find-ns (core.clj:3657)
        clojure.core/the-ns (core.clj:3689)
        clojure.core/ns-resolve (core.clj:3879)
        clojure.core/ns-resolve (core.clj:3876)
        clj.core/create (NO_SOURCE_FILE:7)
```

Once you understand the following you will understand your original problem:

```
user=> (def bar [1 2 3])
user=> (defmacro foo [x] [(class x) (pr-str x)])
user=> (foo (get bar 2))
[clojure.lang.PersistentList "(get bar 2)"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is this a macro in the first place? It seems a normal function would do in this case.

Remember that `config` is bound to the literal value you entered, so if you do

```
(def c {:ns 'foo})  
(create c 1)
```

`config` is going to be just `'c`, not the map referenced by `c` at runtime.